# Visit web url by crosswalk for iOS

Tags: html, ios, iphone, crosswalk

I just used crosswalk in android for months. Now I want to use crosswalk on iOS and follow the [guide](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/ios/quick_start_guide.html) on 
and i can run the demo.
but i revise the content of index.html in www directory of sample code,add

```
<a href='www.xxx.com'>mywebsite</a>
```

in index.html,then run the echo project.i find i could not go to `www.xxx.com` in iOS 9+ simulator when i click the "mywebsite",an "a label" in index.html.my Xcode is 7.1 and my OS X  is 10.11.
I want to ask experts why I could not go to internet website by url using crosswalk for ios.
I could visit internet website by URL in webpage when I use crosswalk on android.

Any light or reply would be appreciated.

Comment: Try replacing www.xxx.com with the website you want. Perhaps xxx.com exists, but is not likely the one you want.

Comment: www.xxx.com is my code mask.the real website is www.baidu.com,you understands wrong.but also,thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

In the myApp-info.plist file (target->Info tab), you need to set the key `App Transport Security Settings` -> `Allow Arbitrary Loads` to `true`

[image: App Transport Security Settings]

Apple has now disabled access to non-https websites by default, so you need to explicitly allow them in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on

> info.plist
>   open as Source Code and
>   add this snppet

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
```

> clean (shift+cmnd+K) and Run the project.